# Android studio canvas get center

Tags: java, android

> look I am new to android but have some java knowledge

I learnt

[to draw text in canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

[to get width](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#getWidth())

[to get height](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#getHeight())
but how to put the text in the centre of canvas no matter how big the device, the canvas is
I want to do this in java without XML change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Paint text = new Paint();
 text.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

 int xPosition = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
 int yPosition = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((text.descent() + text.ascent()) / 2)) ; 


 canvas.drawText("Hello World", xPosition, yPosition, text);
```

Comment: thanks but before marking solution what is `((text.descent() + text.ascent()) / 2))`

Comment: you need to find the center of the text, so that will get the center of your text. If you don't use that then the text is centered in respect to the bottom of the text rather than the center.